# Adding onclick Attribute to <a> tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link button that I want to change it `onclick` callback function when clicked:

I am using `.attr()` to change the `onclick` event but it simply doesn't work.

```
$('#' + test).text('Unlike');
$('#' + test).attr("onclick", "return deleteLikeComment('"
        + CommentsWrapper + "','" + activityID + "', '" + test + "');");
```

But it simply doesn't work.

I just want to switch the callback method when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why are you attaching the event with an attr?

Why not just do like so:

```
$('#' + test).bind("click", function()
{
    //functionality that you were trying to add using attr can now go inside here.
});
```

Comment: ...or just `.click(function () { /* ... */ })` instead of bind.

Comment: @Bears yeah you are right. That is the shorthand way to write what bind does.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#' + test).click(function() {
    return deleteLikeComment(...);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use "[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)" instead of attr()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch the callback method every time the link is clicked, use [**`.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). It alternates between the two provided functions.